How to Pass Dynamic Parameters (e.g., Current Date) in Databricks Workflow UI
I'm setting up a job in the Databricks Workflow UI and I want to pass parameter value dynamically, like the current date (run_date), each time the job runs. In Azure Data Factory, I can use expressions like @utcnow() to calculate this at runtime. However, I want to achieve the same in Databricks, where the run_date parameter would be automatically calculated and passed at runtime without having to hardcode or manually update it.
For example, in the notebook, I am currently using this to get the parameter:
run_date = dbutils.widgets.get("run_date")

Is there a way to configure dynamic parameters in the Databricks Workflow UI, or does this require external handling (e.g., through scripts or APIs)?

import datetime
import requests
current_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
job_params = {
"job_id": your_databricks_job_id,
"notebook_params": {
"run_date": current_date
}
}
response = requests.post('https:///api/2.0/jobs/run-now', json=job_params, auth=('token', your_databricks_token))

The above is for the use of requests for API call.can you try this.

As you mentioned that you want to use a parameter in the UI for current date (run_date)
You can use the  syntax
{{runtime.parameters.parameterName}}

and create a parameter in the UI and pass the key.
And I have tried the below code:
import datetime
import requests
Datetoday = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
job_params = {
    "job_id": 308445560035795,
    "parameters": {
        "parameterName": Datetoday
    }
}
response = requests.post(
    'https://<Your Databricks instance>/api/2.0/jobs/run-now',
    json=job_params,
    auth=('token', '<Databricks token>')
)
print(response.json())

Results:
{'run_id': 40676880654841, 'number_in_job': 40676880654841}


In the above formatting  the current date in required format
Defining the job parameters, including the dynamically set parameter
Making the API call to trigger the job with the dynamic parameter
